# Updating search results URL path for a list item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list that uses a custom display form (CustDisplayForm.aspx). I recently renamed this file in Designer to CustDispForm.aspx. Clicking items on the list view goes to the renamed form ok.  But when I do a search from the list the search results URL path is still pointing to the original name (CustDisplayForm.aspx).

On a couple of list items I changed an image or two that where in them. For these that I've updated an image on, the search result path shows correct with the new name. So I've tried opening a saving other items (which don't contain images) but it doesn't update. I figured re-saving each list item would trigger an update.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I the links are updating on their own now. I guess the search crawler took a few minutes to re-index the items. Looks like they are correct now.